# Oracle EF 6 Code first: How to secure the password field in the connection string in app.config

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, connection-string

I am developing an Windows application with Oracle EF 6 Code first. It works fine, however, the password is stored as a plain text in the connection string in app.config: 

`<connectionStrings>
  <add name="OracleDbContext" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="User Id=UsrName;Password=password;Data Source=ds" />
</connectionStrings>`

What is the best practice to secure the password? I tried to load the connection string and provide the password at run time. Then pass the whole connection string to DBContext via constructor:

```
    public class OracleDbContext : DbContext
    {
       public OracleDbContext(string connectionstring)
           :base(connectionstring)
//            : base("name=OracleDbContext")
        {
        }
    ...
    }
}

public OracleDbContext CreateDbContext()
{
        ConnectionStringSettings settings =    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleDbContext"];
        string connectString = settings.ConnectionString;

    OracleConnectionStringBuilder builder = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder(connectString);
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(builder.Password))
    {
          builder.Password = "password";
    }

    return new OracleDbContext(connectString);
}
```

but, It failed with an error "Unable to complete operation. The supplied SqlConnection does not specify an initial catalog or AttachDBFileName."

Answer (score 0):

In [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) you will find some information about encrypting connection strings inside web.config / app.config.

Comment: I don't want to encrypt the whole connection string though, just the password

Answer (score 0):

I use this way to separate the connectionstring for user.config, but this can easy be tweaked for inserting user/pwd in runtime.

```
<appSettings file="user.config">
<add key="db" value="DATA SOURCE=server:1521/instance;PASSWORD=password;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=user"/>
```

```
 public static string CreateEFConnectionString()
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["db"];
        var builder =
            new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(
                "metadata=res://*/EF_Model.csdl|res://*/EF_Model.ssdl|res://*/EF_Model.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;")
            {
                ProviderConnectionString = connectionString
            };
        return builder.ConnectionString;
    }

   using (var en = new Entities(Dbutils.CreateEFConnectionString()))
        {}
```

.

```
public Entities() : base("name=Entities")
    {
    }

    public Entities(string connectionstring) : base(connectionstring)
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }
}
```